# Restriction of scalars and prime splitting

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

Assume $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is a number field, and $p$ a prime in $\mathbb{Q}$ that may split in $F$.

For an algebraic group $G$, letting $G_p = G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, do we have
$$Res_{\mathbb{Q}}^F G_p = \prod_{v \mid p} G_v$$
where the $v$'s appearing here are places (primes) in $F$ dividing $p$.

Answer (score 0):

If we denote the Weil restriction $\mathrm{Res}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{F}G$ by $G_{1}$, then by definition:
$$G_{1}(\mathbb{Q}_{p})=G(\mathbb{Q}_{p}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}F)\simeq G\Big(\prod_{v|p}F_{v}\Big).$$
Assume that $G=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, where $A$ is a Hopf $F$-algebra. We have:
$$G\Big(\prod_{v|p}F_{v}\Big)=\mathrm{Hom}_{F-\mathrm{algebra}}\Big(A,\prod_{v|p}F_{v}\Big)\simeq \prod_{v|p}\mathrm{Hom}_{F-\mathrm{algebra}}(A,F_{v})\simeq \prod_{v|p}G(F_{v}).$$
This is the result you want. Actually we have $\mathrm{Res}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{F}G(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})=G(\mathbb{A}_{F}).$